# Is this the table name?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to learn SQL queries, and I've encountered things like this:

```
 SELECT name FROM customer_list t 
 WHERE ...
```

What does the t mean? Is it like the name of an instance of that table?

Thanks!

Comment: `t` is called an *alias* or *correlation name*. It's basically a shorthand that you can use for the rest of the query to qualify which table you're referring. It doesn't have to be a single letter and so it probably makes sense to use an alias that facilitates understanding the query. On the other hand it can be very confusing to just use names at random like `a, b, c` simply because they fall alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

The `t` is an alias that you can refer to instead of the table name in your query. If you have only one table you're querying from it isn't very useful, but it comes in hand when you have multiple tables (e.g., in `join` clauses and you want to avoid writing the entire long table name whenever you refer to it. E.g.:

```sql
SELECT t.name
FROM   some_long_table_name t
JOIN   some_other_long_table_name s ON t.id = s.id
```